# Is this ADC's data output correct ? (LTC1273BCN)

Tags: adc, hardware

Why is the period when the waveform should be 1 going between a 5V and VREF(2.4)?

I have set the ADC as specified in the 'typical application' datasheet(see below).

The two traces represent data outputs from the ADC I expect one to be 0 while the other is 1.

http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/127356fa.pdf

Thanks,

[image: The output for the ADC pins d11 and d10]

Comment: You're inventing problems that does not exist. Your oscilloscope trace shows that it toggles between about 1.5 volt and 4 volt. What makes you think Vref has anything to do with it?

Comment: A schematic would be good so we can understand what the ADC is driving.

Comment: What are we looking at here? What do these two traces represent in terms of the circuit you have actually built?

Comment: Shouldn't the data output be going from 0V to 5V as the supply is 5v? I've set the ADC up as shown in the 'Typical Application' part of the DataSheet.

Comment: Sorry I have just updated the question, the traces are data outputs from the ADC I expect one ot be 0 while the other is 1

Comment: You still need to provide a diagram of your test setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: Since you failed to add a schematic or even explain what exact pins are being probed, my answer is partly based on guesswork.

> Why is the period when the waveform should be 1 going between a 5V and VREF(2.4)?

The signals you probed are clearly driven to 0.4 V for a logic low and to 4 V for a logic high. The signal also periodically falls rather slowly to a 1.6 V (not 2.4 V, VREF has nothing to do with it) intermediate state.
This is called *tri-stating*, where the ADC stops driving the outputs high or low when data is not being requested from it, instead letting the data lines float in a high impedance state. This allows the designer to e.g. connect multiple ADCs to the same microcontroller pins without having them "fight" each other.

[image]

- /CS stands for "conversion start". Driving this line low starts a new analog to digital conversion.
- /RD stands for "read data". Driving this low enables the data line output drivers, driving this high tri-states the data lines to a high impedance state.
- /BUSY is driven low by the ADC when a AD conversion is progress.
- HBEN is for selecting which bits to read when using just 8 data lines. When it is driven high, the lowest 8 outputs (7...0) are replaced by the highest 4 bits (11...8).

As to why the yellow trace falls to ground while the blue trace contains data and vice versa, I have no idea. There isn't just enough information in your question.